Newton's classification of cubic
I was reading that in 1704 Newton classified the cubic curves in 14 genera and 78 species (6 species are descovered after Newton [reference: 'QUADRIC, CUBIC AND QUARTIC CONES' by
ANATOLY B. KORCHAGIN AND DAVID A. WEINBERG]. The classification is reasumed as:

I am interessed on the first class, cubic hyperbolas, but I only found some curves of the first 4 genera (on site: enter link description here )
This first 4 genera are characterized by 3 asimptotes and respectively no diameter, one diameter, 3 diameter (of simmetry) and case in wich the asymptotes are concurrent.
Can someone help me find references on other genera, please?
Ps. on wikipedia russian site there are 12 curve of genus 2, 2 of genus 3 and 4 of genus 4. The original 'Enumeratio Linearum Tertii Ordinis' of Newton is very arcaic.
Where i can found a complete classification based witch correlated canonical equation?

Possibly useful: Sir Isaac Newton's Enumeration of Lines of the Third Order, Generation of Curves by Shadows, Organic Description of Curves, and Construction of Equations by Curves, Translated from the Latin, with notes and examples, by C.R.M. Talbot, 1860. Freely available at Google Books AND University of Michigan Historical Math Collection AND Internet Archive.
